# Can't install and use acpi_call on Fedora 37

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, acpi, kernel-module

Fedora 37 Workstation 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64

I downloaded `acpi_call` from [here](https://fedora.pkgs.org/37/rpm-sphere-noarch/acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch.rpm.html), and `rpm -qa | grep acpi_call` returns `acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch`, so it's installed.

And `rpm -ql acpi_call` returns list of acpi_call files at `/usr/src/`, and they exist

In `/var/libs/dkms/` I also have `acpi_call` folder

**However**, `/proc/acpi/call` **does not exist** and `lsmod | grep -q acpi_call` returns **nothing**.

After trying to **uninstall** `acpi_call` with `sudo dnf remove acpi_call` I'm getting:

```
Error! The module/version combo: %{module}-1.1.0 is not located in the DKMS tree.
error: %preun(acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 3
error: acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch: erase failed
Error! The module/version combo: %{module}-1.1.0 is not located in the DKMS tree.
error: %preun(acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 3
error: acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch: erase failed
```

Same with `rpm -e`:

```
 ❯ rpm -qa | grep acpi_call                                                                                !1622 zluka
acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch
acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch

 ❯ sudo rpm -e --allmatches acpi_call                                                                      !1623 zluka
Error! The module/version combo: %{module}-1.1.0 is not located in the DKMS tree.
error: %preun(acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 3
error: acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch: erase failed
Error! The module/version combo: %{module}-1.1.0 is not located in the DKMS tree.
error: %preun(acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 3
error: acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch: erase failed
```

However, I don't get errors with `sudo dnf --setopt=tsflags=noscripts remove acpi_call` (but folder `/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/` after it still exist, so I delete it manually) and after it `rpm -qa | grep acpi_call` returns nothing.

But after **installing** `acpi_call` again I have this:

```
Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/source -> /usr/src/acpi_call-1.1.0
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Certificate or key are missing, generating self signed certificate for MOK...
Key file /var/lib/dkms/mok.key not found and can't be generated, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Certificate or key are missing, generating self signed certificate for MOK...
Key file /var/lib/dkms/mok.key not found and can't be generated, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 -C /lib/modules/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/make.log for more information.
warning: %post(acpi_call-1.1.0-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 10
```

`/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for acpi_call-1.1.0 for kernel 6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64 (x86_64)
Thu Feb  9 03:37:07 PM EET 2023
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.o
/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c: In function ‘init_acpi_call’:
/var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c:355:53: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  355 |                                                     &proc_acpi_operations);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                     |
      |                                                     struct file_operations *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c:6:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:110:122: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘struct file_operations *’
  110 | struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct proc_ops *proc_ops);
      |                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1856: /var/lib/dkms/acpi_call/1.1.0/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64'
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use acpi_call-1.1.0 on a 5.6+ kernel. Use a version after [this patch](https://github.com/nix-community/acpi_call/commit/2554f05ec7a0fb042e6454c39e28faf4de159ac0). Ideally 1.2.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: after `sudo make install` I'm getting `cat: ../Downloads/acpi_call-1.2.2/modules.order: No such file or directory`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it for a thinkpad? https://github.com/julianpoma/acpi_call This seems to have the modules.order.

Comment: now `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'kernel//home/neucoas/dev/acpi_call/acpi_call.ko', needed by '__modinst'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1781: modules_install] Error 2` after `sudo make install` and entering `'/usr/src/kernels/6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64'`